# Toggle View site information popup from browser using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, web, browser

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVEk5.png

I wanted to toggle the above site information pop up, primarily to enable users reset the permission. is there any way doing this using JavaScript?

I tried to search everywhere and was unable to found explanation for this

Comment: I very much doubt you can.

Comment: I thought i have seen it on website somewhere. it is pretty fair if it is not possible too.

Comment: Some websites can toggle the extension tabs. so it can be possible?